# What's the term for N-PP expressions such as "lady-in-waiting"?

Tags: syntax, terminology, morphology

Does anyone know or can suggest a term for the following expressions:

```
lady-in-waiting  
brother-in-law  
sergent-at-arms  
bride-to-be  
etc.
```

Expressions like those above are special for (at least) two reasons:
1. The plural attaches to the first noun, rather than to the entire expression, hence

```
ladies-in-waiting  
brides-to-be
```

but not

```
*lady-in-waitings 
*bride-to-bes
```

2. The dependent PPs do not seem to be modifiable, hence the next examples are bad:

```
*lady-in-long-waiting  
*bride-to-be-late
```

There is more that distinguishes these expressions from nouns with adjunct PPs, but this should suffice as background.

Any ideas what these expressions are called? Or do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I believe dependency theories talk about "head-initial" and "head-final" constructions. That's the distinction here; the head noun comes first (and gets pluralized) and is followed by some modifier that doesn't get inflected. _Attorneys general, brides-to-be, ex-mothers-in-law-to-be_. Normally modifiers precede the head noun: _rail cars, bean soups, pony rides, snake bites_.

Comment: @jlawler Everything is either head-initial or head-final in DGs. Hence this is not much of a distinction. The compound _make up_ is also head-initial, but clearly not of the type addressed in my question.